# How can I query a single item based on the primary key from a db2 table?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code that I can use to return a list:

```
List<T> RunQuery<T>(string s) where T : new()
{
    List<T> data = db2.Query<T>(s);
    return data;
}
```

I execute that like this:

```
RunQuery<Phrase>("SELECT * FROM Phrase WHERE Selected = 1")
                                .OrderBy(x => x.PhraseId)
                                .ToList();
```

But how about if I just want to get one single phrase based on the unique primary key:

```
var p = ..
```

How can I get this from db2? Should I also use a Query or Execute? I am a little bit unclear on this and would appreciate if someone can give me an example generic function that I could use and call to return the information for a single Phrase or other type of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generic `RunQuery<T>` class that you have should work for both single and list object.

You just need to use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) to get one single phrase based on the unique primary key. Assuming primary key columnn is `PhraseId`:

```
var p = RunQuery<Phrase>("SELECT * FROM Phrase WHERE PhraseId = 1").FirstOrDefault();
```